# Why am I getting authentication error when trying to run PowerShell script from task scheduler?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-task-scheduler, mail-server

```
$pass = Get-StoredCredential -Target 'domain.in'
Send-MailMessage -UseSsl -Credential $pass -From 'sender mail` -To 'receiver mail' -Subject 'test1' -Body 'tst' -Attachments 'C:\Users\V-Connect-Akash\Downloads\test.txt' -SmtpServer 'smtp.office365.com'type here
```

So this script retrieves the credentials stored in windows credential manager and authenticated it with the smtpserver. When I run this script manually I don't see any error I receive mail without any error. But when I run same script with task scheduler I get error "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream".

Is there something that I need t take care of before running this script using task scheduler.

Comment: Because you running it from a different (system?) account than where the credentials where created? What happens when you try to [decrypt the credential](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/decrypt-powershell-secure-string-password/) under the scheduled task?

Comment: Hi iRon, I have stored the credentials in this system with the help of CredentialManager.

Comment: What account is the task using?  Task Scheduler default to run using the System Account which does not have an Environment.  Usually the solution is to use Run As and select an account with an environment.

Comment: Hi, yes you are right task scheduler was running this task as Administrator and I was executing this script without Admin so when I ran it with admin I got same error, Sol was to change securityprotocol to TLS12, but I still don't get the reason for this. See I was opening ISE normally and I was signed in on the server by built in admin, and I didn't get any error, but doin with run as Admin I am getting error.